# CSS: Alterar posición relativa de dos <span>

Tags: html, css

Dada la siguiente estructura HTML:

```
<form class="cancion-lista-<?=$id_lista?> cancion-lista cancion-no-publica row d-flex" method="post" action="<?=url_base?>recopilatorios/indice" data-id-cancion="<?=$id_cancion?>"> <!--Bloque con cada una de las canciones de cada lista-->

    <span class="puntos" style="transform: translateY(-2px);"> <!--Información de la canción-->

        <span class="numero-decada" data-id-cancion="<?=$id_cancion?>"><?=$orden?></span> <!--Puesto en el recopilatorio-->

        <span class="">
            <span class="font-italic"><?=$titulo_cancion?></span>
            <span> de </span>
            <span class="font-weight-bold"><?=$nombre_autor?></span>
            <span>(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="<?=$recopilatorio?>"><?=$ano?></button>)</span>
        </span> <!--Resto de datos-->

    </span>

</form>
```

Que se traduce en cada una de estas celdas mediante un bucle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría elevar un poco `<!--Resto de datos-->` con respecto a `<!--Puesto en el recopilatorio-->` para que el texto quede también centrado verticalmente dentro de la celda? He probado a alterar el `margin` y el `padding` y a usar `transform: translateY()` pero no hay reacción.

**EDICIÓN:**

Código CSS de la clase `puntos`:

```
.puntos {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.puntos:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
} /*Trunca el texto con puntos suspensivos cuando es demasiado largo*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Con css, en la classe `puntos`, añade las siguientes propriedades:

.puntos {
...
display: flex;
align-items: center;
...
}

Comment: `<span class="puntos" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">`. Funciona, pero entonces desaparecen los puntos suspensivos del `text-overflow: ellipsis;` que lleva la clase `puntos`. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Comment: Intenta sustituir `display: flex` por `display: inline-flex`. Si no funciona, adjunta el código css para que pueda verlo mejor.

Comment: El comportamiento es el mismo. Te he adjuntado el código que me pides en el mensaje original.

Comment: Lo he resuelto repitiendo la clase `puntos`, poniéndosela también al `<span>` `<!--Resto de datos-->`.